# ESRI Directions widget version 4. Adding Stops?

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

Is there a way to add stops programatically to the latest Directions widget, or must I use the widget GUI?  (I see that it is still 'beta')

Version 3 of the JS API has this function:
[Version 3 add stops](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/3/jsapi/directions-amd.html#addstops)

Answer (score 1):

The Directions Widget is still in a beta state, so probably some methods are still not available (visible).

You can find a `stops` property in the [DirectionsViewModel](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/api-reference/esri-widgets-Directions-DirectionsViewModel.html#stops), which provides the communication and data manipulation logic for the Directions widget.

```
var directions = new Directions({
  viewModel: { // autocasts as new DirectionsViewModel
    stops: //attribute name used to specify stops
  }
});
```